# Using altitude to find a point on a line form a point not on it

Tags: tkz-euclide

I have the following code:

```
 \documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B} % Define B
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[B]({atan(4/3)}:3){A} % Move 3 units at the calculated angle to get A
    \tkzDefSquare(B,A)\tkzGetPoints{G}{F}
    \tkzDefSquare(A,C)\tkzGetPoints{K}{H}
    \tkzDefSquare(C,B)\tkzGetPoints{D}{E}
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = red!50 ](A,C,K,H)
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = blue!50 ](C,B,D,E)
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = green!50](B,A,G,F)
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = orange,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](A,C,K,H)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](C,B,D,E)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](B,A,G,F)
    %\tkzDrawAltitude(D,E)(A) \tkzGetPoint{L}. 
    %\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,D,C,E,F,G,H,K,L)
    %\tkzDrawSegments[thick]( A,E A,D B,k F,C A,L)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use the commented lines to get the point L but it does not work any ideas on why, or a better suggestion.

Comment: Use `\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto D--E](A) \tkzGetPoint{L}` command.

Comment: or `\tkzDefLine[altitude](D,A,E) \tkzGetPoint{L}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was raised in the last questions on `tkz-euclide`. In the latest versions, with the separation of calculations and drawing, some macros have been abandoned or modified. The difference between `tkzDrawLine or tkzDrawSegment` and `tkzDrawAltitude` is that the latter requires calculations.

In the documentation, you'll find `tkzDefLine[altitude](A,B,C)` then just draw.

```
\tkzDefLine[altitude](A,D,E) %  pascal974
\tkzGetPoint{L}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,L)
```

or

```
\tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto D--E](A)
```

is good ( Andrey L. )

With `tkz-elements` and lualatex

```
\documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-elements}

 \begin{document}
   
   \begin{tkzelements}
   z.B = point : new (0,0)
   z.C = point : new (5,0)
   z.A = point : polar (3,math.atan (4/3))
   T.ABC = triangle : new (z.A,z.B,z.C)
   S.AB = T.ABC.ab : square (swap)
   z.G,z.F = S.AB.pd,S.AB.pc
   S.AC = T.ABC.ca : square (swap)
   z.K,z.H = S.AC.pd,S.AC.pc
   S.BC = T.ABC.bc : square (swap)
   z.D,z.E = S.BC.pd,S.BC.pc
   L.DE = line : new (z.D,z.E)
   z.L = L.DE : projection (z.A)
   \end{tkzelements}
   
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzGetNodes
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = red!50 ](A,C,K,H)
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = blue!50 ](C,B,D,E)
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = green!50](B,A,G,F)
    \tkzFillPolygon[fill = orange,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygons[line width = 1pt](A,B,C A,C,K,H C,B,D,E B,A,G,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](B,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](K,C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,G,H)
     \tkzLabelPoints(D,E,L)
   \tkzDrawSegments[thick](A,E A,D B,K F,C A,L)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]